# SQL get date from timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where all my data have a unix timestamp as a integer, the integer is the amount of seconds since 1.jan 1970.(like what Time.now.to_i returns in ruby http://www.unixtimestamp.com).

Is there any way i can get the date from 1447277423 in SQL? I need to group the rows by date.

I want this to be done in a view, and not use another script to do it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the unix timestamp to date only (since you don't want hours/seconds), then group by it.

```
SELECT * FROM table
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(date_timestamp, '%Y %m %d');
```

Or, if you don't want to actually group them and just want them outputted all in order, ORDER BY instead.

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY date_timestamp
/* when ordering, it doesn't matter so much if its the whole timestamp or not since the date comes first in the timestamp */
```

To go one further, you can SELECT the formatted date as well

```
SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(date_timestamp, '%Y %m %d') as date_Ymd FROM table
ORDER BY date_timestamp;
```

[FROM_UNIXTIME docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Answer (score 1):

Just use FROM_UNIXTIME():

```
group by DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(your_unix_timestamp_field))
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the nice part of unix timestamps, you can just treat it as an integer.

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE date >= 1447277423
```

Hope this helps

Comment: OP needs to group by date. This won't suffice.